# MEVN stack unable to deploy

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, heroku

I have a project where I try to locally and on Heroku run a MEVN application. Both are not working at the moment.

I have my server.js file in the main folder. Then inside the 'client' folder is the Vue 3 project. Inside there I have run `npm run build` which created a dist folder containing the index.html file.

When I run both locally and on Heroku I can go to '/api/users' and the JSON is shown in the browser. But when I navigate to '/'

I have tried changing the `public` in the server.js to `dist` but this did not fix the problem.

I get the following error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat `/Users/stephen/Documents/stephen/project/client/build/index.html`

My server.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});

//DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ user: 'test' })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server starter on port " + port));
```

Comment: `/api/users` is declared unconditionally, but not the other handlers: is your `NODE_ENV` equal to `production` (i.e. can you `console.log` something from inside that `if`-block)?

As an unrelated side note, you could configure `cors()` instead of overriding the middleware with handcrafted options: see [cors package options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

Comment: @StockOverflaw Thanks for the answer. I have tried setting the other handlers outside of the if statement. But they never get called. I get the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/stephen/Documents/stephen/project/client/build/index.html'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));`?

Comment: @Taxel I have tried to change it. But it did not fix the problem.

Comment: if you got this `ENOENT`, it's that the catch-all route (for `*`) is called - just with the wrong stuff inside it. (EDIT: oops, actually more simple: is your file really at `/Users/stephen/Documents/stephen/project/client/build/index.html`, as shown in the `ENOENT` dump?)

Comment: I always get this error. It does not matter if I put the route for `*` inside of outside the `if`-block. If I put it outside the if block and add a console log. I have noticed that this route never gets called. The `/` route always gets called.

Comment: wait what do you call the `/` route? I see only 3 routes: `/api/users`, the `express.static` and `*`

Comment: @StockOverflaw Ow sorry I probably haven't copied the code correctly. I have updated the code. Now it includes the `/` route.

Comment: so, this `/` route is the same as your catch-all, and there is no file at `/Users/stephen/Documents/stephen/project/client/build/index.html`: check the path in the (built) files to fix it there, I guess?

Comment: Stephen if you share your code with us, it will be easier to help you.  #1 Does this file exist? /Users/stephen/Documents/stephen/project/client/build/index.html #2 I think your third paragraph is incomplete. #3 Does your npm run build result contain index.html, css, js, etc ?